# MEAN Stack Amazon Passport Auth

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I'm attempting to use Amazon Passport in my MEAN application for authentication, but I'm running into a cross origin error. My application is set up like this:

View:

```
<a id="LoginWithAmazon" ng-click="vm.auth()">
  <img class="responsive-img amazon-button"/>
</a>
```

Controller:

```
vm.auth = function () {
  Auth.login()
      .then(function () {
        $location.path('/');
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        vm.error = err;
      });
}
```

Service:

```
vm.login = function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.post('/auth/amazon')
    .then(function (res) {
      console.log('SUCCESS! ', res);
      deferred.resolve();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('ERR: ', err);
      deferred.reject(err.data);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

And in my Express/NodeJS context...

Passport is configured like this:

```
passport.use(new AmazonStrategy({
    clientID: config.amazon.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.amazon.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:9000/test"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('SUCCESS AUTH: ', profile);
        process.nextTick(function() {
            return done(null,profile);
        });
    });
  }
));
```

Express route:

```
router.post('/auth/amazon', function (req, res, next) {  
  passport.authenticate('amazon', function (err, user, info) {
    console.log('Err? ', err);
    console.log('User: ', user);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

When I try to make the authentication request, I am getting the following error:
[image]

I've tried using `<a href="{{amazonUrl}} target="_blank">Login with Amazon</a>` but to no avail as well. I've whitelisted `http://localhost:9000` on Login with Amazon's configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you make an AJAX request to an endpoint you should **redirect** (302) to. The endpoint possibly contains a login page and the user should be able to see it and use it.

Make sure you follow the oauth specs and you don't issue an AJAX request prematurely. The protocol requires you first redirect to their login page and then, only when you have the one-time code, you issue an AJAX request to exchange the code for an access token.